# Rack-Cors and sending headers on 500 or 403 errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rack

I'm starting to work with rack-cors for a necessary cross site javascript / api implementation.  Everything works fine when its working correctly, but if something in the front-end triggers a 500 error on the back-end, the client never receives the proper headers.  You just see this on the client-side dev tools:

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is this just how CORS works?  Or is it some bad setup I have with rack-cors when sending this header?  I tried to send the header manually during an unhandled error condition, but didn't have any luck - so I'm going on the assumption that this is just how it works, and my client side needs to be able to realize and handle that.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the correct HTTP header values on the server. Here's a short article (using PHP, but adapting to Ruby should be easy) on how this can be done: [CORS That Works In IE, Firefox, Chrome And Safari](https://404it.no/en/blog/cors_that_works_in_ie_firefox_chrome_and_safari)